# Translate ImageMagick CLI to PHP Imagick API

Tags: php, api, imagemagick, command-line-interface, imagick

I have problem with translating ImageMagick CLI command to Imagick PHP API.
I looked at threads about it on Stackoverflow but people there used other commands...

```
> convert color-to-add.png test.png -compose CopyOpacity mask-with-alpha.png
> composite -compose multiply test.png mask-with-alpha.png compose-result.png
```

**I can't use exec method.**

I still try do do something with this but I spent a lot of time and have nothing to this moment (I started to think that it is imposiible in pure API). Maybe for someone it will be easy. I would be glad ;-)

If I will find soulution I will write this but my morale is very low now...

Comment: Have a look here http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
$img1->compositeImage( $img2, imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0 );

$img1->compositeImage( $img2, imagick::COMPOSITE_MULTIPLY, 0, 0 );
```

Have a look at the documentation - [here](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.compositeimage.php).

Comment: Wow... what a easy solution (= the best), now I understand this better. Really thanks! ;-)